# App Store Server Notifications delayed and duplicate transaction Id coming

Tags: ios, duplicates, in-app-purchase, subscription

We have integrated App Store Server Notifications to listen iOS in app purchase subscriptions. I have set 5 minutes interval for my sandbox account. Some time notifications coming on time, but some time it is delayed. Will this be happen in production also? Any proper way to test this?

For failed transactions, transaction ID becomes same as previously succeeded transaction ID. How failed transaction Id is being generated actually?